# SSIS - cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, ssis, etl

Having an issue importing multiple CSV files.

I'm using SSIS Flat File Source combined with OLE DB Destination to import the files.

The data type of the columns is String `DT_STR`, I have also tried changing them to Unicode string `DT_WSTR` but to no avail.

Comment: I think that the question is unclear. You should specify which columns you are mentioning (source or destination). Besides, have you tried to change the flat file columns data types or the destination columns?

Comment: You need to change the data type of your SQL Server tables from varchar to nvarchar.